# Can I seal the frost-hewn breach without killing everyone?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm in Rymrgard's temple and want to seal the frost-hewn breach as the god instructed me ("Into the White Void" quest). The problem is that those pesky priests of Rymrgard don't want to let me into some parts of the temple and will immediately attack me if I try to enter there. Talking  to Vesgel doesn't achieve anything apart from triggering a rather lewd comment from Durance.

I've searched the accessible parts of the temple, but without success. Do I really have to massacre everyone in the temple to fulfill this quest, or is there a less bloody way.

Answer (score 3):

Peaceful enterance depends on sneaking I'm afraid. It is however achievable quite easily and possibly doesn't require any skill in it. You do need some mechanics though. Also, due to how the game conversations work, you only need a single character to get through, the rest waiting safely by the exit.

Start with the south - there is an unguarded locked door there, ready for you to enter (key to which is findable somewhere in the accessible zone).

Immediately turn left - on the right the door leads to multiple hostile priests. They won't bother you or try to notice you, unless you approach it.

Again two choices, this time not so important - south has some items (and a key to the other door), north has the path you need to take.

There you enter a big room with a throne-table thing, and little stars on the floor pattern. On a star on the right there is a hidden switch to open the wall. At the far side of the room there is the only enemy that can possibly notice you if you're not careful - but it's nothing to really worry about, and you can hide behind the table waiting for opportune moment to move.

Once you're through the secret door, you encounter a group of pale elves - they are your target, and are not hostile.

It is worth noting, that to fulfill Rymrgard's will you will need to pass a resolve 17 check, or kill them anyway.

Comment: One can also help the leader cross the breach so he kills himself and you don't fight.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't replayed this to confirm, but I noticed that there's a Resolve 17 dialog option that you only get if you bring the Orlan druid companion Hirivias with you when you speak to the pale elf leader. I don't mean leave him in the main hall while you sneak with your main character either, I mean he has to be physically present with you.

I managed to sneak my whole party through the temple without killing anyone, and when I spoke with the leader, Hirivias made a bunch of comments while I was speaking with him. After I tell the leader that "You can't go against the will of the gods", or something like that, that's when the Resolve 17 option appears, allowing you to convince the elves to leave peacefully, after which you can then close the breach.

I've noticed that there are other quests like this that depend on you having a certain party member or a character class in your party, in order to resolve peacefully/without killing anyone.

Comment: That's incorrect - you do not need that companion for the Resolve check and peacefull quest resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you sneak through the secret passage, don't go for the stairs. Head toward the northern lip as you first enter and you'll get a dialog scene. Give the head priest the shard from the god and tell him it will allow his people to go into the void. Everyone disappears, so no bloodshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly go through the western part of the temple if you have enough mechanics skill in your party. You definitely won't kill "everybody" as a lot of people are in the eastern part, and the resistance is limited.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to sneak my way through most of the forbidden temple quarters (north/eastern parts) and got the key to release their prisoner.

There is also a hidden secret door which leads to the grand hall from the south-west wall (on the opposite side there is only one priest you can sneak past).

But upon entering the grand hall where the breach is located I did not find a peaceful way either... If you want the breach sealed, the high Priest and his people have to die.